# Trying to make GET request in objC using NSURL

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, google-chrome, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to make this request in an iOS app [image]

I've already logged into the website using `NSURLConnection`, the following code is in the completion handler:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *requestGrades = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/Assignments?_=1395809728907"]];
[requestGrades setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:requestGrades queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *gradeResponse, NSData *gradeData, NSError *gradeError) {
    
    if ([gradeData length] > 0 && gradeError == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",requestGrades);
        NSLog(@"grade Response = %@ \ngrade Data = %@", gradeResponse, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:gradeData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"grade Error = %@", gradeError);
    }
}];
```

The response I get in my app is something like:

```
grade Response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x109627500> { URL: https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/Assignments?_=1395809728907 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 234;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 05:21:52 GMT";
    Expires = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 05:21:52 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 05:21:52 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    Vary = "*";
    "X-AspNetMvc-Version" = "4.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
```

Which, as you can see, is not the same as Chrome's response (most notably, the `Content-Length` - I only got a length of 234 - I was hoping for something like 31189).

Digging around in the `Network` section of the chrome developer tools, looking at what chrome does when I try to request the data, is:
[image]

Chrome, when I click the button to fetch some data, makes 2 `GET` requests (the two pictures). The first one gets the data I'm trying to get for my app and the second which seems as if it doesn't really do anything. BUT the response the second chrome request is getting is the same response that I get when I try to make the first chrome request from iOS (the first picture, should return a `Content-Length` of 31189).

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with my `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x109507800> { URL: https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/Assignments?_=1395809728907 } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "public, max-age=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 234;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 06:11:35 GMT";
    Expires = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 06:11:35 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 06:11:35 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/7.5";
    Vary = "*";
    "X-AspNetMvc-Version" = "4.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }

Comment: I just looked over both the request URLs again, I think I'm missing something. They both look like a `GET` requests to `https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/Assignments?_=1395809728907`.

Comment: Sorry.
<center>
 <div class="appblank" style="padding-top:100px">
  Student Profile
 </div>
 <img alt="" src="/novi/StudentPortal/images/appblank.jpg" />
 <div class="copyright">
  <b>Please Make a Selection</b>
 </div>
</center>

Comment: Which is exactly the same data as the the second chrome response from the picture. Which is weird, because I don't have the `True;` in my request

Comment: No, I have to log in before that. I just tried doing the request a couple times and saw that the number `1395809728907` was different each time. I'm not sure where it came from though. I can't find it in the HTML of the page

Comment: I did a couple more requests, and realized that the number is counter. Every time I 'show' or 'hide' the element that creates that request the number is just incremented.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is login to a student and get the student's assignments in html (or whatever else) so I can parse them and display them in an app

Comment: The number shows up when you hit the assignments button on the left side of the page [in this table](http://i.imgur.com/KacWEXT.png)

Comment: Oh wow, I just used Charles, it's like a more advanced version of chrome's network developer tool. How do I get the request and response to become readable? Is it not UTF-8 formatted?

Comment: I turned on SSL proxying, I can't see where the number came from though. It just seems like a counter. Here's my charles file, if it makes any sense to you. https://www.dropbox.com/s/m2hjhgqnu9xsxb5/MistarCharles.chls

Comment: I found it in the source of the website though, it's a value that gets loaded from a js script called `sarea[i]`. Here's a picture [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/teQ1Ftm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a little testing, i have confirmed that you have to do the following four `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` requests:

- Login at `/novi/StudentPortal/Home/Login`
- Go to the portal page at `/novi/StudentPortal/Home/PortalMainPage`
- Set the student banner `/novi/StudentPortal/StudentBanner/SetStudentBanner/XXX`, where `XXX` is the `id` value for the row associated with the particular student in the portal page
- Request the assignments from `novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/Assignments` (no `?_=xxxx` parameters needed; it looks like `AjaxLoad` Javascript used that to keep track of the requests, but we don't have to worry about that here)

I notice that if you skip either of those middle two steps, the request for the assignments will fail, as shown in your question. (Frankly, this makes me question some of the design choices in that system you're interfacing with, but I assume you have no say over that.) But if you do all four, you'll get the HTML associated with the assignments.

By the way, while parsing this HTML, you might be inclined to use `NSXMLParser` or regular expressions, but I'd suggest you consider Hpple (see Ray Wenderlich's [article on parsing HTML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)).

Comment: Right, so I can get to step 3 with no real problem, I have three nested `NSURLConnection`s. I can't get the `?=xxxx` for the last step. With that, I *should* be able to download the associated data

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the last number from `AjaxLoad`?

Comment: @AndrewSB You don't need the `?=xxx` for the assignments URL. For the `SetStudentBanner` (which is just adding `/xxx` to the end), you have to parse the HTML from the `PortalMainPage`.

Comment: What do I do instead? If it helps at all, here's my code: https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAGradeReport.m#L61
The link is to the line with the request that has the number

Comment: Oh, right. To get the `userID` from `SetStudentBanner`. I've already got the `HTML` from that page, parsed it and got the `userID`. I'm stuck *after* that

Comment: I thought that at first too, but what happens is that when the `assignments` URL (`novi/StudentPortal/StudentBanner/SetStudentBanner/20050494`) is opened, the data I need hasn't been fetched. Using `NSURLConnection`, it just downloads the page immediately, it can't wait for the AJAX to bring the grades onto the page.
So that's why I'm trying to access the `?=xxx` `URL`. Because the's where the page after you `setStudentBanner` loads the grades from.

Comment: Here's what my thing was till now
http://postimg.org/image/7b6tod9mz/
What do you mean by assignment page? Do you just mean this page:
http://postimg.org/image/9v31om4gv/ ? Because it uses AJAX to get the assignments, so `NSURL` methods can't see the data

Comment: Ohhh, let me try that, I'll post the data and response

Comment: Call to `setStudentBanner`? `POST`ing the `studentID`?

Comment: Writing that request rn. Thank you