# NSURLConnection call javascript function with a GET request

Tags: javascript, ios, nsurlconnection

I have a `NSURLConnection` that `GET`s a page. I was wondering if it was possible to send a js request to the page (hitting a `HTML` radio input) and then `GET`ting the page.

The request itself `GET`s this page:[image]

What I want to do is before `GET`ting the page, is to hit the `Show All` `radio input` on the right (the `HTML` of the `input` is the highlighted line in the picture).

So the `radio input` does not have a value, as inputs usually do, it has a class (`ShowAll`).

`ShowAll` appears again in the source of the webpage as a js script,

```
$(".ShowAll").click(function () {
            var schk = $(this).is(':checked');
            var sarea = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
            // if id starts with tr_, strip off the tr_ to get the area
            if (sarea.substring(0, 3) == 'tr_') {
                sarea = sarea.substring(3);
            };
            if ($("#hStudentID").val() != "-1") {
                // has the data been loaded yet?  If not, load the data now.
                if ($("#b" + sarea + "Loaded").val() == 'True') {
                    AjaxLoad($("#SP_" + sarea), '/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/' + sarea + '^' + schk);
                    var pos = eval($('#SP_Detail').scrollTop());
                    var ntop = eval($("#tr_" + sarea).offset().top);
                    $('#SP_Detail').animate({
                        scrollTop: (pos + ntop) - 125
                    }, 1000);
                };
            };
        });
        var bisshown = false;
        $(".isshown").each(function () {
            if (this.value == "True") {
                bisshown = true;
            };
        });
        if (bisshown == false) {
            if ($("#hascontent").val() == 0 && $("#haslinks").val() == 0) {
                $("#noarea").show();
            } else {
                $('#SP_Detail').animate({
                    scrollTop: (0)
                }, 1000);
            };
            $("#lnk2print").hide();
        } else {
            $("#noarea").hide();
            $("#lnk2print").show();
        };
        $("#erSubmit").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#erReset").prop("disabled", true);
    });
    function SetMenuHeight(menuHeight) {
        var height = 0;
        var body = window.document.body;
        if (window.innerHeight) {
            height = wi…
```

So is it possible to send a `request` (or something else) that would first hit this radio input and *then* `GET` the page?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly, however if you send a request to a page to select a radio button (which you cannot) and then call the page again, the page you would receive would be the initial view.

From the code you have provided it looks like when the checkbox is selected, an AJAX request is performed and the UI is updated accordingly.

If you require the radio button to be selected to show the relevant data, the ideal way would be to load the page in a `UIWebView` object. Once the request is completed, use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method on the `UIWebView` to run your JavaScript which would be something like:

```
document.getElementById('_chkassignments').checked = true;
```

Then, once the AJAX call has been performed by the in-built JavaScript you can fetch the updated content of the page.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: *Usually*, that would work. But here, the element has no attribute 'checked'. So making it true just toggles the radio input. It doesn't actually bring the data that comes with calling `class=ShowAll`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, you don't invoke the client-side JavaScript within a `GET` request.

There are two approaches to this sort of problem:

1. Like we did in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652279/trying-to-make-get-request-in-objc-using-nsurl/22671805), fire up [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com), run the web page in your web browser and take a look at the requests that are being generated, and then you can write `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLSession`, or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) code that generate those requests manually. That's one way to interact with your web server and retrieve the results that you would otherwise retrieve via JavaScript in a web browser.
2. If you really need to run the JavaScript (and if I understand your business problem, you don't need to in this case), the other approach is to load the page in a `UIWebView`, and then you can use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to invoke some JavaScript in the web view. You can only run the JavaScript within a web view, though, not via a basic `GET` request.

In this case, the Javascript that you're running is basically expanding and collapsing what is currently visible (and if necessary, retrieving the additional information via AJAX, if it hasn't already). So there's no point in running that particular JavaScript unless you're displaying it in a web view. If you just want the data, figure out what requests are being made of the web server, write your requests to do that, and then you bypass the complexities of trying to interface directly with the JavaScript.

Comment: I'm going to be doing (1.) later tonight. I'm not sure if I'm good enough at web debugging to recognize what happens though.

Comment: So *this* is the one where you need the `?_=xxxx`. To get ALL assignments. 
Did you have any ideas at all to find that number? I can't think of anything

Comment: @AndrewSB I agree that reverse engineering the JavaScript and analyzing network requests in Charles is a daunting exercise, but if you're trying to extract data from a web server, it's probably the way to go. The web view approach makes more sense to me if you need the web view and only need JavaScript to interact with it, rather than the other way around.

Comment: And if you use the web view approach, you again don't have to worry about `?_xxx`, but this time it's because it should take care of that for you (you're not issuing a series of requests, like the first approach, but just loading the initial URL and letting the user use web view to navigate, effectively, you're launching you own little web browser).

Comment: Letting the user navigate webpages is something that would defeat the purpose of making this application. I should practice and get better at reverse engineering

Comment: Ok, so I've come back to this project, been working on other parts of the product.
I've looked around *everywhere*, Charles, searching all through the source files, it just seems to pull theses `?_=xxxx` out of nowhere, throws it into the request URL and gets the information I need.

Comment: @AndrewSB I don't think you need to worry about the `?_=xxxx`. That appears to be something that the HTML page needs to keep track of the multiple Ajax calls, but when making those requests from Objective-C code, directly, it's not needed. When I retrieved the homework content, I didn't use the `?_=xxxx` and it retrieved the appropriate content without incident.

Comment: Yea, I can get *some* of the homework content using `https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/LoadProfileData/Assignments`, but without the rest of the grades loaded (using some `AJAX` request with the `?_=xxxx` that gets called when you hit the Show All button).
So when I do the request (the one I have for grades right now), it gives me about 8 or 9 assignments, but if I go onto the page manually and Show All the assignments, there are about 50. I'm trying to get at the 50

Comment: I'm tied up with some other tasks right now, but I'll see if I can take a look tonight.